# How to execute command every 10 seconds (without cron)?

Tags: bash, cron

When I execute `cron` I get this fault

> cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied

So, how to do it without `cron`?

P.S. I want to check if file in svn has changed and I have a special script for it.

Comment: If you do not have permission, then try run cron with `sudo`.

Comment: Bear in mind cron won't do something every 10 seconds, the most granular it gets is once a minute.

Comment: If you want to make cronjobs, you've to run `crontab -e` to start the editor. To list the current crons, run `crontab -l`

Comment: @Anonymous i don't know root password, so sudo won't help me.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To access your personal `cron` configuration you should use the command `crontab -e` (to edit your cron table).

Alternative is the `watch` command:

```
watch -n10 command args
```

Finally, to monitor filesystem events more effectively, you could use `inotifywait`, from `inotify-tools` package.

Comment: It's worth noting, perhaps, you would better wrap your command(s) inside double quotes or you may end up with unexpected results. `watch -n<timeout> "command(s) arg(s)"` like `watch -n2 "ps ux | grep ss5"`

Comment: I found it hard to get `watch` to accept long, complicated commands using pipes and quotes. The while loop below worked, but of course one should *always sleep first* to avoid runaway pids.

Comment: @rjurney: it should be enough to wrap the whole command in quotes, single or better double: `watch -n10 "ls -l | grep $foo"`

Comment: @enzotib The problem comes when there are quotes in the commands, as quotes within quotes within (god help me) quotes approaches impossible in bash. In theory it should be possible but I rarely achieve nested quotes in bash without giving up and going a different route.

Answer (score 35):

You can write a shell script that has `sleep` in a while loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    sh special_svn_script.sh
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: `while true` does not require square brakets, otherwise "true" is interpreted as a string, and every string is as good as "true".

Comment: @enzotib so you might as well write while around

Comment: While this works you should *always sleep first* because something may occur causing the sleep step not to be reached, in which case you've got a runaway pid flooding something.

Answer (score 4):

[**gnome-schedule**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-schedule) (click the button to <kbd>[**Install now!**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-schedule)</kbd> using your Software Center)
 is a graphical user interface that leverages the power of vixie-cron, dcron and at to manage your crontab file and provide an easy way to schedule tasks on your computer. It supports recurrent (periodical) tasks and tasks that happen only once in the future. It is written in Python using pygtk.

**Awesome features**

- Supports custom titles and icons for your tasks so that they are more easily to keep track of
- Templates support so that you won't have to create the same task again and again; these are saved in gconf and may easily ship them with, say, a Linux distribution
- If run as root, you can edit any user's crontab and "at" tasks.
- Human-readable strings like "Every hour" instead of "0 * * * *"
- Advanced mode for crontab experts
- Provides a "panel applet" where you can manage tasks from a dropdown menu
- Predefined common expressions like: every minute, every week, tomorrow, next week
  A calendar allows you to choose the day you want a task executed