# How to record chrome cpu and memory usage

Tags: log, system-monitor

Is it possible to record google-chromes cpu and ram usage??

with terminal or other software that will do the same task ??

Thank you in advance

Comment: try starting with top, run it in a terminal.

Comment: yes but I want to record the processes

Comment: `ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd` use the pid of google-chrome, pipe the output to a log file, and run the command as often as you wish, either manually or with a script. If you have a problem update you question with what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have a small problem this does not record the stats. it shows stats only once

Comment: `ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd >> $HOME/google-chome.log`

Comment: Thank you again but the problem still is there it does not logs stats it just only prints once.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82616/how-to-execute-command-every-10-seconds-without-cron

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install sysstat`

`man pidstat`

Of possible additional  interest, `man sar`, `man mpstat`